# Effecient way to compare values with different date range

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to build a report which has week's sales data by department by date (which I have done using Matrix) and compare it to weeks sales last year. Report would be run weekly. I am wondering which approach would be most efficient:

- 1) generate separate data sets - 1) for 1 weeks data and 2) for 1
  week a year ago and then compare these values;
- 2) create 1 data set    for a period of 1 year + 1 week and insert
  calculated fields in the data set;
- 3) create 1 data set for a period of 1 year + 1 week and    insert
  calculated fields with expressions inside the report
- 4) any other.
  Thanks

Comment: Is your datset a SSAS cube or SQL Server Databse?

Answer (score 0):

If you tables are well indexed, then I'd suggest you go with the first approach - It'd reduce the data to be compared. I feel that pulling data from one year in past would be a less expensive than comparing 2 week's data out of one year's data.

You could use the week number of any given week to efficiently pull data for any week based on the date range.

Comment: what function would you use to calculate the difference between values from different data sets? Simple formula doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could select department, week # N, year & sales (SELECT sales as negative for previous year and positive for current year) for current year and for previous year. This would give you 14 rows which could be grouped by department, week # N & Year to give week's total of sales by department and year. Once you do this, you'd have 2 rows per department - one with negative sum of sales for previous year & other with positive sum of sales for current year. Now you can group this again on department and sum the week's total - which would give you the difference. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Rio - Please help me with some sample data for more accurate solution

Comment: I don't seem to be able to add an image, but my issue is following - I have a last weeks total in one column(by department) calculated from Data Set 1 and weeks total 1 year ago (by department) calculated from Data Set 2. I want to calculate the difference between these 2 numbers using expression =ReportItem!WeekTotalThisY.Value/ReportItem!WeekTotalLastY.Value, but it doesn't work